# Google Maps javascript API- Map object recenters after applying KML layer. How do I prevent this?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps javascript API question - Map object recenters after applying KML layer. How do I prevent this?

I created a simple page with a map. When I apply a simple polygon KML, it recenters and zooms the map. Any ideas?

```
    var myOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(27, -97),
            zoom: 17,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),            myOptions);
    var buildings = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://mysite/site/buildings.xml');
    buildings.setMap(map);


    //i tried this to recenter and zoom, but no dice.
    var posn = new google.maps.LatLng(27, -97);
    map.setCenter(posn);
    map.setZoom(17);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the [preserveViewport option](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#KmlLayerOptions). From the documentation:

> By default, the input map is centered and zoomed to the bounding box of the contents of the layer. If this option is set to true, the viewport is left unchanged, unless the map's center and zoom were never set.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it a KMLLayerOptions object through the constructor:

```
var buildings = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://mysite/site/buildings.xml',{preserveViewport:true});
```